# csv output is wrong

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to read a csv table and parse it into a 2D array, which is working, but when I have some empty cells next to a value in my table, then it will output the value to the right.

For example I have this table:

[image: My Table]

'test1' has the following position in my 2D array:

```
array[28][4];
```

and when I type:

```
System.out.println(array[28][4]);
```

it should output 'test1', but instead what my program will output is 'test2' (array[28][5]).
Everyother values in my table(as seen in the picture) are working perfectly fine, so my guess is that is has something to do with the empty cells and the delimiter(";");

Here is my code:

```
try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(upload.pathName));
        String strLine;
        for (int i = 0; (strLine = reader.readLine()) != null; i++)
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(strLine);
            scanner.useDelimiter(";");
            int j = 0;
            System.out.println("row: " + (i+1));
            while (scanner.hasNext())
            {
                String value = scanner.next();

                if(value == null || value.equals(""))
                {
                    System.out.println("null: " + (j+1));
                    j++;
                }
                else
                {
                    array[i][j] = value;
                    System.out.println("column : " + (j+1) + " = " + array[i][j]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
    System.out.println("Output: " + array[28][4]); //output is test2 instead of test1
```

In my code I am trying to skip empty cells by checking if they are "null" and all the cells that have a value get added to my 2D array.

Anybody got a solution/can tell me where my mistake lies?

Comment: The source data would be better presented if it were in the delimited format, rather than in the editing tool snapshot provided. This way someone could reproduce the problem more easily. Currently there is still the unknown of the actual file to understand. Note also, that your ';' delimiter is not universal for CSV. Most locales use an actual comma ',' for this. To make it location insensitive, switch to TSV (tab separated value) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think jp-jee is right:

```
String[] splittedLine = strLine.split(";");
for (int j = 0; j < splittedLine.length; j++ ) {
  array[i][j] = splittedLine[j];
}
```

should do the job, with empty cells beeing "" instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Line 29 of your file: `,,,,test1,test2`

From the `Scanner#next()`JavaDoc:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.
>    A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches
>    the delimiter pattern. [...]

According to this, the empty cell `A29` is being ignored by the `Scanner`, which shifts your values one column to the left. Giving any value to `A29` will result in the expected output.

If the documentation quoted above is true, how can the last value be returned by `next()`, although not followed by the delimiter? Same question is valid for the first value in each line, which is not preceeded by a delimiter.
Since both *are* returned, the JavaDoc must be lying to us.

Investigating the source code of the `Scanner` class, you can find out that *leading delimiters* are being skipped and "partial tokens" are being returned by `next()` aswell.

That being said, I'd suggest to avoid the `Scanner` in your case.

```
for (int i = 0; (strLine = reader.readLine()) != null; i++)
{
    String[] splittedLine = strLine.split(";");
    array[i] = splittedLine;
}
```

Note: The code above behaves different from yours for empty Strings, which are now written to the array - consider replacing those by `null` if needed.

Comment: hey, I tried your method, but there is still one value less than there should be, when I use a csv thats looks like this: ;;;;;;;;I1;J1;K1